# A particular relation between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd like to consider the consequences of the following relation between two *symmetric* square matrices $A$ and $B$
$$SA^{-1}S^T=B$$
$$S^TB^{-1}S=A$$
There are no inversion conditions on the matrix $S$.

Now, say we have the eigenvalues/vectors of $A$, can we say anything about the eigenvalues/vectors of $B$?

**Edit:** I might also add the conditions on $S$
$$S^TS=aA^2$$
$$SS^T=bB^2$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: The conditions don't sound right. If $A$ and $B$ have not the same sizes, then $S$ is not a square matrix. Hence it is either tall or fat. If it is tall, the first condition will imply that $B$ is singular. If $S$ is fat, the second condition will imply that $A$ is singular.

Comment: Yes you're right. What I had in mind were infinite dimensional matrices $A$ and $B$ that live in different Hilbert spaces. For example, $A_{n,n'}$ has indices $n,n'=0,1,\dots$ but $B_{n,n'}$ has indices $n,n'=1,2,\dots$. They have the same size. That inconsistency should go away in this case. In the finite case I guess the only way to make this consistent is to consider them equal in size.

Comment: I think it's enough to consider them equal size, I removed the comment about unequal sizes in the question.

Comment: If they are of equal size then $S$ is invertible ( and for example orthogonal) and $B^{-1}=SAS^T$ and $ B=SA^{-1}S^T $

Comment: Is it really true that $S$ must be invertible?

Comment: Yes. If you write $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$, I would implicitly assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible. Hence, $0 \neq \det(B) = \det(S)^2 \cdot \det(A^{-1})$, thus $\det(S) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric matrices of the same sizes, the conditions $SA^{-1}S^T=B$ and $S^TB^{-1}S=A$ imply that $S$ is invertible. Hence the two conditions are equivalent and they simply mean that $A$ is congruent to $B$. It follows from Sylvester's law of inertia that $A$ and $B$ have the same inertia, but the exact values of their eigenvalues are completely unrelated. E.g. any two positive definite matrices are congruent to each other, but they have different eigenvalues in general.

With also the conditions $S^TS=aA^2$ and $SS^T=bB^2$, a more precise relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ can be obtained. Since $S$ is invertible, $aA^2$ and $bB^2$ are positive definite. Hence $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. By taking determinants on both sides of $SA^{-1}S^T=B,\,S^TS=aA^2$ and $SS^T=bB^2$, we further see that $ab=1$.

Now, from $S^TS=aA^2$, we obtain
$$
S=\sqrt{a}Q|A| \text{ and } S=\sqrt{b}|B|U^T\tag{1}
$$
for some real orthogonal matrices $Q$ and $U$. Thus
$$
B=SA^{-1}S^T
=(\sqrt{a}Q|A|)A^{-1}(\sqrt{a}Q|A|)^T
=aQAQ^T.\tag{2}
$$
That is, $B$ is orthogonally similar to $aA$.

In addition, $(2)$ implies that $\sqrt{b}|B|=\sqrt{a}Q|A|Q^T$, while $(1)$ implies that $\sqrt{b}|B|=SU=\sqrt{a}Q|A|U$. It follows that $U=Q^T$. Thus, assuming that $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular symmetric matrices, the general solution to the set of equations $S^TB^{-1}S=A,\ S^TS=aA^2$ and $SS^T=bB^2$ is given by $b=\frac1a>0,\,S=\sqrt{a}Q|A|$ and $B=aQAQ^T$, where $Q$ is real orthogonal. Unless at least two of the variables among $A,B$ and $S$ are known, $Q$ remains arbitrary and we cannot determine the relationship between the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Very nice solution! If I'm not mistaken it looks like you proved that $B$ and $aA$ have the same eigenvalues? Also I think that if $Av_n=\lambda_nv_n$, then $Qv_n$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $a\lambda_n$.